# Moving multiple chained layers separatey in GIMP

Tags: gimp, layers

I put a set of layers in group A and linked them and another set of layers in group B and linked them.  If I use the move tool to move the layers in group A, the layers in group B also move.  This does not happen if I use the scale tool; the layers scale separately.  The only way to move the layers separately is to unlink the layers in group B.

How can I move chained layers separately?

Comment: "*This does not happen if I use the scale tool; the layers scale separately*" In my version the linked layers are scaled.

Comment: This would make a nice feature request at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/issues/

Comment: @xenoid I am using 2.10.14. I was confused why scaling worked independently of other layers whereas moving did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible. Linking layers works regardless of groups. You'd have to unlink layers you don't want to move together.

Use groups to organise your layers instead. Use links only when you want to link layers regardless of grouping.

With the move tool, and the group selected in the layers panel, you can toggle between "Pick a layer or guide" and "Move the active layer" by holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> when you click and drag .  Also the scale tool can be used on all layers within a group if you first select the group in the layers panel.

Example

[image]

Comment: Ok, so the trick is to use Shift+Click to move the layers in unison.  No need to link the shapes for moving them together.

Comment: @user2233706 yes basically.

Answer (score 0):

A possible work around it to use link on groups (and not layers) when needed, so you only have to link/unlink groups (a somewhat smaller number).